# Not able to run spring boot application through Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a simple Spring Boot application and trying to run it in Docker.
The application is working locally, but when I run it in Docker, the webpage doesn't load in the browser. And it is starting in the Docker console properly without any fail.

**Dockerfile**
[image]

Docker run command: [image]

Docker Console Output: [image]

Comment: How are you accessing the webpage?

Comment: I am accessing like this -http://localhost:8080/hello-world.

Comment: In the logs it is clearly stated that context path is `' '`. So try removing `hello-world`. The url should be `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world")
 public String helloWorld() {
  return "Hello World";
 }         Above is rest controller mapping and hence the URL

Comment: It looks like you've attached three images to your question in place of the code you're running.  Can you remove these images and replace them with the actual Dockerfile, `docker run` command, and console output (as text)?

Comment: It is fixed. Problem was I am using Docker toolbox which is linux VM  thus we need VM ip instead of localhost.